# I get redirected to stackoverflow.com when I click on a migrated question

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I click on this question (see the link is correct):

[image]

But I got redirected here:

[image]

I've also recorded a video if it can helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's [supposed to work like that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17552/why-do-migrated-questions-lack-redirection-via-http-response-status-code-301-mov), although it certainly threw me for a loop when I clicked it. I didn't realize I was on SO right away.

Appending `?noredirect=1` to the P.SE URL lets you view [the original question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/32590/unicode-to-ascii-conversion-closed?noredirect=1).

Comment: Others redirected questions stays in P.SE for me. Example this one: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/32556/what-are-best-cities-for-a-java-developer-to-live-and-work-in-america-closed

Comment: That question is migrated in a different direction. The one in your post is P.SE -> SO. The one in your comment is SO -> P.SE.

Comment: Here's the original question for the one in your comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561945/what-are-best-cities-for-a-java-developer-to-live-and-work-in-america Note the SO link, but you will be redirected to P.SE.

Comment: Got it, thanks Anna

Answer (score 2):

This is by design -- we feel a migrated question should take you directly to the destination, since otherwise it's just another click to get to the actual question and any answers.